# Version for openssl variable x509name in .net

Tags: .net, windows, dll, openssl, version

.NET looking for an older version of OpenSSL. Looking for 1.0.0a when the latest is installed. Methods aren recognized but will not execute on running project. 
[image: errorduringruntime]

Answer (score 0):

Steps to correctly install... get latest version. Try the latest version of OpenSSL.NET ([0.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/files/openssl-net/0.5/))

Put the libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll directly into project folders to guarantee working. Then make a reference to the ManagedOpenSSL.dll.

[why-doesnt-net-find-the-openssl-net-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396164/why-doesnt-net-find-the-openssl-net-dll)